# Is it possible to list and count unique substrings in a column in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I'm trying to make a Google sheets to organize my books and I like to tag my books with things like "sweet romance" or "martial arts fighting", etc. Things that are more specific than genres (in the AO3 style for those familiar).

I wanted to try and make a graph showing how many occurrences of each tag there was and also maybe filter results based on tags I'm interested in and tags I don't want to see. For that I would need to both list each unique substring of the tags column and count their occurrences, but I can't figure out how to do that.
For example say I have to rows:

| Book | tags |
| --- | --- |
| Book 1 | fluff, angst, found family |
| Book 2 | fluff, getting together, major character death, found family |
| Book 3 | getting together, found family |

I would want to make something like this:

| Tags | # of occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| fluff | 2 |
| angst | 1 |
| found family | 3 |
| getting together | 2 |
| major character death | 1 |

I would also already have made sure all values are lower case and with no special characters.

I have tried separating tags into different columns and then filtering the unique values from the whole range but there are simply too many tags in most entries for this to be very feasible. I take my entries from a forms so I would need a bunch of fields asking for each individual tag.

One of the first things I tried as well was separating a single response into different columns using the array function, I think (I tried a few different ones I can't remember which was the most successful), but if I remember correctly it wouldn't split them correctly and sometimes there weren't enough columns, if you know a way to do that successfully it might be a feasible alternative (though not the preferred one because it creates a mess).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Λ,tocol(map(tocol(B2:B,1),lambda(z,split(z,", ",0))),1),Σ,unique(Λ),
    {Σ,index(countif(Λ,Σ))})
```

[image]

***`Formula breakup`***

*`Step 1` use [map / lambda functions](https://youtu.be/kUur-tMdTbo) to split all the tags available in `Column_B`*

```js
=map(tocol(B2:B,1),lambda(z,split(z,", ",0)))
```

*`Step 2` use `tocol` function to arrange the data obtained in step1 into one single file(column)*

```js
=tocol(map(tocol(B2:B,1),lambda(z,split(z,", ",0))),1)
```

*`Step 3` finding unique tags from step2 column & using `countif` function to obtain the # of occurences of each tag*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked out super well. Could you maybe explain what you did though? I've never come across a function like this before. Either way thank you so much.

Comment: explanation (at best possible) added to the answer..: